# Laravel InertiaJS Vue 404 when deployed to Hostinger

Tags: laravel, vue.js, deployment, vite, inertiajs

I uploaded my project to Hostinger, only the homepage shows in the website, other components give errors such as : `GET https://appname.com/shop/all 404 (Not Found) vendor-5ByMKR7B.js:3`, I tried to play with the `.htaccess`, I changed `APP_URL` to the app url, added `ASSET_URL`, and also changed `APP_ENV` to `production`:

`.env`

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:kR4cgrq3ND2Ce7ZsHSlsnF/MPinxuAtUod5tQuhS38Q=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=https://example.com/
ASSET_URL=https://example.com/
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=secret_name
DB_USERNAME=secret_username
DB_PASSWORD=secret_password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailpit
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_APP_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

CLOUDINARY_URL=secret_url
API_KEY=secret_key
API_SECRET=secret_api
CLOUD_NAME=secret_name
```

`app.js`:

```
import "./bootstrap";
import "../css/app.css";
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import { resolvePageComponent } from "laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers";
import "primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css";
import { messages } from "./../../i18n";
import PrimeVue from "primevue/config";
import MainLayout from "./Pages/Layouts/MainLayout.vue";
import Toast from "primevue/toast";
import ToastService from "primevue/toastservice";
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";

function getStartingLocale() {
    return localStorage.getItem("locale") || "en";
}

const i18n = createI18n({
    legacy: false,
    locale: getStartingLocale(), // set locale
    messages, // set locale messages
    // If you need to specify other options, you can set other options
    // ...
});

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - Eagles Hospitality`,
    resolve: async (name) => {
        const page = await resolvePageComponent(
            `./Pages/${name}.vue`,
            import.meta.glob("./Pages/**/*.vue")
        );

        page.default.layout = page.default.layout || MainLayout;

        return page;
    },
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        const VueApp = createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) });
        VueApp.config.globalProperties.$route = route;

        return VueApp.use(plugin)
            .use(PrimeVue, { ripple: true })
            .use(ToastService)
            .use(i18n)
            .component("Toast", Toast)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: "#4B5563",
    },
});
```

`vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig, splitVendorChunkPlugin } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: "resources/js/app.js",
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
        splitVendorChunkPlugin(),
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `.htaccess` wasn't there in `public` directory as it's a hidden file and doesn't get uploaded to `Github`, I added it and it worked.